# How to write a short story?

Tags: character-development, short-story

I am working on a computer game right now. Therefore i need a story. First of all I want to write down the plot as a short story as the game has an emphasis on story telling!
So I want to check out how exactly a short story is written. It was a subject back in school, but that is long ago. Plus, perhaps some of you could share useful links or tips (on everything that could help with that issue).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. You do not really want to write a story, you want to make a computer game. And the game should emphasis on story telling, because that always sounds like a got idea. But you have no clue about story telling, so you ask us how to do it. Listen, you will not learn story telling within a week or a month or even a year. If the story is *really* important to your game, hire a writer.

Comment: I'm not working on a AAA-title. It's a private project I am doing with a friend of mine. So we don't want to hire people we wont to learn. The story doesn't have to be perfect. It's about the learning effect and the best possible the two of us can do.

Comment: Hi Dre, welcome. As is, this question is too broad in its scope to provide meaningful answers. You're covering everything from plot, characters, structure, planning, editing ... everything. I suggest having a look at the FAQ http://writers.stackexchange.com/faq for guidelines on questions, and look at previous questions to get a flavour of what I mean, and then try to focus your question so it's more specific.

Comment: (Oh, and this website will likely be a good place for you to start: http://www.theshortstory.org.uk/).

Comment: @Dre - welcome, this question is too broad to be a fit for this site.  If, however, you edit it to ask something more along the lines of "what are the characteristics of a short story?" or "What resources will teach me to write a story for a computer game?" and @ reply to me, it can be reopened as the edited question.  You can also ask a new question along those lines.

Comment: Also, a good game story will not be short - it'll be long an convoluted, with lots of side plots.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how they're written.  That's up to each individual writer.  But in terms of how they're structured...

Short stories tend to have a tighter, simpler plot structure.  Conflict, Rising action, Climax, Denouement.  No subplots, not many secondary characters, etc.  You have one main character, who wants something.  Your character makes a choice, takes action, deals with the consequences.